# How to define column width of TableLayout in my case?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator, android-widget

I have a table layout:

```
<TABLELAYOUT xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"      

    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

   <TABLEROW>
       <TEXTVIEW 
           android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
           android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
           android:text="1">

        <TEXTVIEW 
           android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
           android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
           android:text="2">

         <TEXTVIEW 
           android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
           android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
           android:text="3">

         <TEXTVIEW 
           android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
           android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
           android:text="4">
          ...
          <!--there are 10 columns-->
          ...
    </TABLEROW>
</TABLELAYOUT>
```

There are **10** columns in this table.

My question are:

1. how can I customize each **column width** so that only **4** columns show on the screen??
2. how to set row height?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define the size of the first 4 textView by(screenWidth/4).And another 6 as you like.So you will only see the first 4 columns

Comment: @ Rasel , my point is how to define width of each column? I do not want each column always has the wrapped width of text view.

Comment: Each textView is a column as you are adding it to the tableRow.

Comment: For first 4 TextView use   android:layout_width="80px".See the result.you will understand what to do

Comment: Feeling happy that it helped you